# Broken Slide Stop Clip

Tags: hardware, desk, drawers

[image]In removing my desk drawers, I broke one of the 12 clips when I squeezed the top, it snapped.   Where can I find a replacement?  Is there a name for this type of clip?

Comment: can you loop a nylon cable tie through there? .... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cable_tie ...... you may have to drill a vertical hole through the plastic piece, right where the tab is broken off

Answer (score 3):

These clips are from an individual manufacturer and are not a common hardware item. You could contact the drawer-slide manufacturer, who might provide a clip *gratis*. If that fails, or you wish to experiment, you could fabricate a replacement from springy plastic or even a metal strip cut from a food can (smooth edges to avoid cuts), since you have the other clips as models.

Comment: Many thanks.  Contacted the slide manufacture and they're helping me out.

Comment: @Doug Please follow the convention here and say "thanks" by clicking the "up vote" button. Since this answer seems to have been the one to help you out, please give the check mark a click, too, so others know there's a resolution to the question. And I'm glad you got your drawer working properly!